# Build failed - Build service could not start build operation: unknown error while handling message

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run this command:
ionic cordova run ios -- --verbose

On my Mac Mini, with Xcode installed, I get an error that I am not sure what it is referring to.  Here is the error (I provided some extra lines for context and I do have the Legacy Build system enabled):

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild

2021-02-12 09:37:32.166 xcodebuild[66659:802711] Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=160 "Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=(null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=(null), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdaed0f1d30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "Cannot allocate memory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Allocation or initialization failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize simulator device set.}}}
2021-02-12 09:37:32.168 xcodebuild[66659:802711]  iOSSimulator: [SimServiceContext defaultDeviceSetWithError:] returned nil (Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=160 "Failed to initialize simulator device set." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to subscribe to notifications from CoreSimulatorService., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize simulator device set., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdaed0f27b0 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=160 "Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=(null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=(null), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdaed0f1d30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "Cannot allocate memory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Allocation or initialization failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize simulator device set.}}}}}). Simulator device support disabled.
2021-02-12 09:37:32.221 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open log store at /var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Build
2021-02-12 09:37:32.222 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open Build log store: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Build': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Build” in the folder “Logs”." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Build': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Build” in the folder “Logs”.}. User info: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Build': (513) You don\U2019t have permission to save the file \U201cBuild\U201d in the folder \U201cLogs\U201d.";
}.
2021-02-12 09:37:32.264 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open log store at /var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Package
2021-02-12 09:37:32.264 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open Package log store: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Package': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Package” in the folder “Logs”." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Package': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Package” in the folder “Logs”.}. User info: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Package': (513) You don\U2019t have permission to save the file \U201cPackage\U201d in the folder \U201cLogs\U201d.";
}.
2021-02-12 09:37:32.280 xcodebuild[66659:802657] Couldn't create intermediates directory: You don’t have permission to save the file “Intermediates.noindex” in the folder “Build”.
Couldn't set atribute on intermediates directory: setxattr(/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Build/Intermediates.noindex, com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem, true): No such file or directory (2)
Couldn't set atribute on intermediates directory: setxattr(/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Build/Intermediates.noindex, com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem, true): No such file or directory (2)
Couldn't set atribute on intermediates directory: setxattr(/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Build/Intermediates.noindex, com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem, true): No such file or directory (2)
2021-02-12 09:37:32.773 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open log store at /var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Test
2021-02-12 09:37:32.773 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] IDELogStore: Failed to open Test log store: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Test': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Test” in the folder “Logs”." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Test': (513) You don’t have permission to save the file “Test” in the folder “Logs”.}. User info: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to create log store directory at '/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Logs/Test': (513) You don\U2019t have permission to save the file \U201cTest\U201d in the folder \U201cLogs\U201d.";
}.
2021-02-12 09:37:32.808 xcodebuild[66659:802657] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-16139/IDEFoundation/Buildables/IDEWorkspaceArena.m:1131
Details:  Failed to create workspace arena at <DVTFilePath:0x7fdaef42b970:'/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj” in the folder “DerivedData”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdaec7cd050 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
Object:   <IDEWorkspaceArena: 0x7fdaef41f4a0>
Method:   -createWorkspaceArenaFolderIfNecessary
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fdaec607c20>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Couldn't set atribute on intermediates directory: setxattr(/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Build/Intermediates.noindex, com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem, true): No such file or directory (2)
note: Using new build system
error: Build service could not start build operation: unknown error while handling message: fopen(/var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-fmmaocaaeccvdogvcypgumhupubj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/PIFCache/WORKSPACE@v11_hash=(null)_subobjects=81f2a101a7ac69098e1a397e863616a6-Workspace.lock, wb): No such file or directory (2)

** BUILD FAILED **

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 65
npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.11.4 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.11.4 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxxDev/.npm/_logs/2021-02-12T16_37_32_939Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue with the DerivedData folder. Could you try to execute `chmod -R 755  /var/empty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` ?